# How create scanner screen with particular given area in camera view

Tags: android, android-screen, camera-view

I want to create scanner screen (Image is given below).

[Scanner Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8bVc.png)

For this screen, I aim to display a full-screen camera view where only the central 240x240 area is visible for scanning QR codes. Additionally, the remaining area should be displayed with 50% transparency to provide some visibility while keeping the focus on the central area.

Can anybody help me to create this kind of screen in android without using third party dependencies?

I have tried using CameraSource(`com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector`) and SurfaceView in layout.

In CameraView I can not find a method so that i can allow the scanning the particular area.